# How to convert a PHP array to an associative array, using index as keys?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have the following array:

```
$foo = ["hello", "hi", [5, 10]];
```

I want to convert this to an associative array like so:

```
$foo = [
   "0" => "hello",
   "1" => "hi",
   "2" => [5, 10],
];
```

How can I do this?

### UPDATE

The reason I want to do this is because when I execute the `shuffle` method, I want to know what the original index was.

For example `shuffle($foo)` might return:

```
$foo = [
   "1" => "hi",
   "2" => [5, 10],
   "0" => "hello",
];
```

Comment: Why do you want to quote indexes, which remain numerical?

Comment: Edited my question to include explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your array:

```
$foo = ["hello", "hi", [5, 10]];
```

It's already associative. PHP adds keys for you, so it's the same as doing:

```
$foo = [0 => "hello", 1 => "hi", 2 => [5, 10]];
```

If you use string keys that are numbers, PHP converts them to numbers for you.

Your array doesn't need to be "associative" to make `shuffle` behave as you want. **All PHP arrays are associative.** You are looking for the wrong solution to your problem.

Comment: I realised this after

Answer (score 2):

(See Andrea's answer, this is incorrect)

The only transformation from the previous state is that the keys are strings, rather than integers.

```
$keys = array_map('strval', array_keys($foo));
$values = array_values($foo);
$foo = array_combine($keys, $values);
```

Comment: This is completely pointless. You can't have string keys with numbers in them in arrays - they are automatically converted to integer keys. This will produce an array identical to the original.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to do something like this

The values are already "indexed". If you run

```
$foo = ["hello", "hi", [5, 10]];
echo $foo[0];
```

You will get `hello` (starting from 0)

Comment: I have now explained why I need to do this!

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what you're trying to achive, but as I see you want to convert your array indexes into strings:

```
$_foo = [
   "0" => "hello",
   "1" => "hi",
   "2" => [5, 10],
];
$foo = [];

foreach($_foo as $key => $value) {
    $foo[(string) $key] = $value;
}

var_dump($foo);
```

But I think that's just redicilous, to convert array indexes into strings. I don't know if you're aware, but you already can access your array with indexes: `0`, `1` or `2`.

```
var_dump($foo[1]); // hi
```

Comment: You will produce an array identical to the original.